# R Code: csv file data incorrectly breaking across lines

Tags: r

I have some csv data that I'm trying to read in, where lines are breaking across rows weirdly.

An example of the file (the files are the same but the date varies) is here: http://nemweb.com.au/Reports/Archive/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_20211118.zip

The csv is non-rectangular because there's 4 different types of data included, each with their own heading rows. I can't skip a certain number of lines because the length of the data varies by date.

The data that I want is the third dataset (sometimes the second), and has approximately twice the number of headers as the data above it. So I use read.csv() without a header and ideally it should pull all data and fill NAs above.

But for some reason read.csv() seems to decide that there's 28 columns of data (corresponding to the data headers on row 2) which splits the data lower down across three rows - so instead of the data headers being on one row, it splits across three; and so does all the rows of data below it.

I tried reading it in with the column names explicitly defined, it's still splitting the rows weirdly

I can't figure out what's going on - if I open the csv file in Excel it looks perfectly normal.

If I use readr::read_lines() there's no errant carriage returns or new lines as far as I can tell.

Hoping someone might have some guidance, otherwise I'll have to figure out a kind of nasty read_lines approach.

Comment: ` So I use read.csv() without a header and ideally it should pull all data and fill NAs above.` - it doesn't. You'll need to either a) read the file in two passes: one to work out where your lines of interest start, the next pass to process the CSV from that line, or b) do some `read_lines()` magic on the entire file.

Comment: I've tried reading in the file with an appropriate number of lines skipped (as a test) - it didn't pick up the number of columns correctly. So I don't think this is it.

Meanwhile I've been trying some read_lines() approaches and getting name errors when trying to bind back into a data frame. Stuck in an R purgatory tonight.

Comment: Does the R AEMO package address this, or are you after different NEM data?

Comment: "I've tried reading in the file with an appropriate number of lines skipped (as a test) - it didn't pick up the number of columns correctly." Arg. That makes sense, I didn't think it through. With this kind of thing, I usually pre-process the data with something like Python and push it into a database, then use the DBI tools in R to my heart's content.